# "change password on next logon" remote workarounds?

Tags: active-directory

we have a group of people who work from outside and generally only work using a Terminal Server, and with NLA in place we cannot force password changes as that just sends users into a brick wall and they cannot connect or do anything relevant.

is there some way that

1. Users can change their Password remotely while this option is active

or

2. using a GPO or whatever to wipe this flag from all users in a given OU?

Comment: A GPO cannot direclty manipulate properties of AD objects.  Does your VPN solution (assuming one is in use) not have the ability to change passwords?  Do  you have an email interface that would allow this (like OWA)?

Comment: `with NLA in place we cannot force password changes as that just sends users into a brick wall and they cannot connect` Maybe address the root cause and don't set change password on next logon to begin with?

Comment: @Semicolon the VPN doesnt interact with the AD in any way in the first place, so that option is out

Comment: @GregAskew except this flag is iirc on by default when creating users and resetting passwords and the flag itself isnt generally a bad thing as it is bad to have a password that more people than the actual user know. it's just that the remotedesktop application and/or Terminal Server apparently cant really deal with that.